# Не работает первый проект на Ruby on Rails

Tags: windows, ruby-on-rails

В первый раз сталкиваюсь с ROR, мало чего толком понимаю в нём. Начал изучение ROR с этих двух ссылок:

[Ссылка 1](http://rusrails.ru/getting-started-with-rails#chto-dalshe)

[Ссылка 2](http://railstutorial.ru/chapters/4_0/beginning#sec-install_rubygems)

Хочу создать свой первый проект на ROR. Делаю всё по инструкции, как описано в этих двух ссылках. Далее в консоли ввожу команду:

```
C:\rails_projects\first_app>rails server
```

В консоли выводится такое сообщение:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   43: from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
>   42: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/
>   active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in`require'
>   41: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/
>   active_support/dependencies.rb:249:in `load_dependency'
>   40: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/
>   active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in`block in require'
>   39: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/boots
>   nap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
>   38: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/boots
>   nap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in`require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
>   37: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/boots
>   nap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
>   36: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/boots
>   nap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in`block in require_with_boot
>   snap_lfi'
>   35: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/boots
>   nap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
>   34: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails
>   /commands.rb:18:in`'
>   33: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails
>   /command.rb:46:in `invoke'
>   32: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails
>   /command/base.rb:65:in`perform'
>   31: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor.rb:
>   387:in `dispatch'
>   30: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/inv
>   ocation.rb:126:in`invoke_command'
>   29: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/com
>   mand.rb:27:in `run'
>   28: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails
>   /commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in`perform'
>   27: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails
>   /commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `tap'
>   26: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails
>   /commands/server/server_command.rb:145:in`block in perform'
>   25: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/
>   active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `require'
>   24: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/
>   active_support/dependencies.rb:249:in`load_dependency'
>   23: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/
>   active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `block in require'
>   22: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/boots
>   nap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in`require'
>   21: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/boots
>   nap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
>   20: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/boots
>   nap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in`register'
>   19: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/boots
>   nap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_boot
>   snap_lfi'
>   18: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/boots
>   nap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in`require'
>   17: from C:/rails_projects/first_app/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (r
>   equired)>'
>   16: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.3/lib/bundl
>   er.rb:114:in`require'
>   15: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.3/lib/bundl
>   er/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
>   14: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.3/lib/bundl
>   er/runtime.rb:65:in`each'
>   13: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.3/lib/bundl
>   er/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
>   12: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.3/lib/bundl
>   er/runtime.rb:76:in`each'
>   11: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.3/lib/bundl
>   er/runtime.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in require'
>   10: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/boots
>   nap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in`require'
>   9: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/boots
>   nap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
>   8: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/boots
>   nap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in`register'
>   7: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/boots
>   nap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_boot
>   snap_lfi'
>   6: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/boots
>   nap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in`require'
>   5: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13-x64-mingw
>   32/lib/sqlite3.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
>   4: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13-x64-mingw
>   32/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in`rescue in '
>   3: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/
>   active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `require'
>   2: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/
>   active_support/dependencies.rb:249:in`load_dependency'
>   1: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/
>   active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `block in require'
>   C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cac
>   he/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in`require': cannot load such file -- sqlite3/
>   sqlite3_native (LoadError)

Я неоднократно видел подобные темы в интернете у людей, но я так толком и не понимаю, как решать такие вот проблемы подобного вида. Подскажите, как в моей ситуации решается данная проблема и, что делать мне в будущем, если примерно такая же проблема будет возникать с другими проектами на ROR?

Информация про Ruby и фреймворк ROR:

```
C:\rails_projects\first_app>rails -v
Rails 5.2.0

C:\rails_projects\first_app>ruby -v
ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x64-mingw32]
```

**Gemfile**:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.5.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.0'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
gem 'duktape'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use ActiveStorage variant
# gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.8'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15', '< 4.0'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of chromedriver to run system tests with Chrome
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

**Gemfile.lock**:

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actioncable (5.2.0)
      actionpack (= 5.2.0)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
      websocket-driver (>= 0.6.1)
    actionmailer (5.2.0)
      actionpack (= 5.2.0)
      actionview (= 5.2.0)
      activejob (= 5.2.0)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
    actionpack (5.2.0)
      actionview (= 5.2.0)
      activesupport (= 5.2.0)
      rack (~> 2.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    actionview (5.2.0)
      activesupport (= 5.2.0)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubi (~> 1.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.3)
    activejob (5.2.0)
      activesupport (= 5.2.0)
      globalid (>= 0.3.6)
    activemodel (5.2.0)
      activesupport (= 5.2.0)
    activerecord (5.2.0)
      activemodel (= 5.2.0)
      activesupport (= 5.2.0)
      arel (>= 9.0)
    activestorage (5.2.0)
      actionpack (= 5.2.0)
      activerecord (= 5.2.0)
      marcel (~> 0.3.1)
    activesupport (5.2.0)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      i18n (>= 0.7, < 2)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    addressable (2.5.2)
      public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 4.0)
    archive-zip (0.11.0)
      io-like (~> 0.3.0)
    arel (9.0.0)
    bindex (0.5.0)
    bootsnap (1.3.1)
      msgpack (~> 1.0)
    builder (3.2.3)
    byebug (10.0.2)
    capybara (3.5.1)
      addressable
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.3)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
      rack (>= 1.6.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      xpath (~> 3.1)
    childprocess (0.9.0)
      ffi (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.11)
    chromedriver-helper (1.2.0)
      archive-zip (~> 0.10)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
    coffee-rails (4.2.2)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.12.2)
    concurrent-ruby (1.0.5)
    crass (1.0.4)
    duktape (2.0.1.0)
    erubi (1.7.1)
    execjs (2.7.0)
    ffi (1.9.25-x64-mingw32)
    globalid (0.4.1)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
    i18n (1.0.1)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    io-like (0.3.0)
    jbuilder (2.7.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      multi_json (>= 1.2)
    loofah (2.2.2)
      crass (~> 1.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.7.0)
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.1)
    marcel (0.3.2)
      mimemagic (~> 0.3.2)
    method_source (0.9.0)
    mimemagic (0.3.2)
    mini_mime (1.0.0)
    mini_portile2 (2.3.0)
    minitest (5.11.3)
    msgpack (1.2.4-x64-mingw32)
    multi_json (1.13.1)
    nio4r (2.3.1)
    nokogiri (1.8.4-x64-mingw32)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.3.0)
    public_suffix (3.0.2)
    puma (3.12.0)
    rack (2.0.5)
    rack-test (1.1.0)
      rack (>= 1.0, < 3)
    rails (5.2.0)
      actioncable (= 5.2.0)
      actionmailer (= 5.2.0)
      actionpack (= 5.2.0)
      actionview (= 5.2.0)
      activejob (= 5.2.0)
      activemodel (= 5.2.0)
      activerecord (= 5.2.0)
      activestorage (= 5.2.0)
      activesupport (= 5.2.0)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0)
      railties (= 5.2.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0)
    rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.6)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.4)
      loofah (~> 2.2, >= 2.2.2)
    railties (5.2.0)
      actionpack (= 5.2.0)
      activesupport (= 5.2.0)
      method_source
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (12.3.1)
    rb-fsevent (0.10.3)
    rb-inotify (0.9.10)
      ffi (>= 0.5.0, < 2)
    rubyzip (1.2.1)
    sass (3.5.7)
      sass-listen (~> 4.0.0)
    sass-listen (4.0.0)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
    sass-rails (5.0.7)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 6)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (>= 1.1, < 3)
    selenium-webdriver (3.14.0)
      childprocess (~> 0.5)
      rubyzip (~> 1.2)
    sprockets (3.7.2)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.2.1)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    sqlite3 (1.3.13-x64-mingw32)
    thor (0.20.0)
    thread_safe (0.3.6)
    tilt (2.0.8)
    turbolinks (5.1.1)
      turbolinks-source (~> 5.1)
    turbolinks-source (5.1.0)
    tzinfo (1.2.5)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    tzinfo-data (1.2018.5)
      tzinfo (>= 1.0.0)
    uglifier (4.1.17)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0, < 3)
    web-console (3.6.2)
      actionview (>= 5.0)
      activemodel (>= 5.0)
      bindex (>= 0.4.0)
      railties (>= 5.0)
    websocket-driver (0.7.0)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-extensions (0.1.3)
    xpath (3.1.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)

PLATFORMS
  x64-mingw32

DEPENDENCIES
  bootsnap (>= 1.1.0)
  byebug
  capybara (>= 2.15, < 4.0)
  chromedriver-helper
  coffee-rails (~> 4.2)
  duktape
  jbuilder (~> 2.5)
  puma (~> 3.11)
  rails (~> 5.2.0)
  sass-rails (~> 5.0)
  selenium-webdriver
  sqlite3
  turbolinks (~> 5)
  tzinfo-data
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
  web-console (>= 3.3.0)

RUBY VERSION
   ruby 2.5.1p57

BUNDLED WITH
   1.16.3
```

Comment: Правильно понимаю, вы из-под винды пытаетесь всё это сделать? Самым лучшим выходом тут будет перейти на IDE (как это рекомендовано у Хартла), или поставить линукс второй системой. Под виндой вы всё время будете бороться с ошибками вместо того, чтобы учиться. И ещё совет - соблюдайте версии гемов, если планируете заниматься по Хартлу, иначе ещё пачка ошибок вам обеспечена

Comment: Да, всё верно. А вы можете, пожалуйста, подсказать бесплатные IDE для RoR и какой линукс лучше установить себе на компьютер для разработки на RoR (есть много вариантов ОС, к сожалению не особо разбираюсь в линуксе).

Comment: Совсем бесплатную облачную IDE не подскажу, но очень недорого на https://c9.io В линуксе я тоже не особо разбираюсь, потому как успела не так уж долго из-под него поработать, у меня была Ubuntu Gnome

Comment: Проблема в SQLite. [Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17643897/cannot-load-such-file-sqlite3-sqlite3-native-loaderror-on-ruby-on-rails) **предлагаются самые разные решения. Попробуйте, начиная с самых простых**. Работать можно на любых системах. Но лучше конечно Linux (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS) или Docker. Борьба с ошибками - это тоже обучение. В разработке по другому не будет.